# ES6 module and compatible with non-module js

Tags: javascript, browser, es6-modules

I'm wondering if there are some ways of making non-module JS like:

```js
// my-api.js
function MyAPI() {
   this.classVar = null
}

MyAPI.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  this.classVar = {something: 3}
}
```

Compatible with ES6 modules. I tried to put this code into `my-api.js`:

```js
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = MyAPI
}
```

But I get `The requested module '/static/my-api.js' does not provide an export named 'MyAPI'` when trying to import whether with `import MyAPI from '<url-of-backend>/static/my-api.js` or `import { MyAPI } from <url-of-backend>/static/my-api.js`

I stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615189/8204956 this response, but it requires another level of indirection.

I'm trying to make non-module JS compatible with es6 module in order to move to module smoothly in a large codebase.

Comment: You're mixing ES6 module syntax with the CommonJS module mechanism.

Comment: Why are you set on keeping the file as a non-module? Really you should make it a module by adding `export { MyAPI }` or using `export default function MyAPI() { … }`

Comment: Because I don't have 1 file, but thousands of them, and, as I said, big project, so I can't migrate everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing this to make the transition to ES6 module's, one idea is just put your API's into `globalThis`, by doing this it doesn't matter what module loader your using.

eg.

```
globalThis.myAPI = ......
```

And then -> `import "./my-api"` `<script src="./my-api"/>`  `require("./my-api")` etc. doing ->

```
const api = new globalThis.MyAPI(); //this will work no matter what loader
```

One caveat, make sure you don't use functions that already exist on the global, `MyAPI` should be fine, but doing `globalThis.atob` etc could cause issues.

And then as you transition to using ES6, you can then gradually remove them.